# Any good libraries for doing tearaway tabs in Java?

Tags: java, swing

Was thinking about implementing tearaway tabs on a Java project I'm working on.  Wondering if there are any libraries out there that make it easy, or if I'm on my own.  :-)

Comment: Do mean drag tab to open in another window .. like this firefox example http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgUn8UCJe6Y ?

Comment: A tearaway tab is a UI tab that you can remove from the current frame, drag out into space, where it populates it's own new frame.  Example, Google Chrome, drag one of those tabs off of the main frame and into desktop space.

Comment: I hope you get some good answers, because I'd love to use tearaway tabs in some of my Java projects.

Comment: Are you looking for a Swing solution? Or SWT? ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[JIdeTabbedPane](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm) supports floating tabs though I'm not sure if you can just drag them out.

Correction:

This is what you're looking for:

[What are good docking frameworks for Java/Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/304874/84378)

From that link, the [demo of MyDoggy](http://mydoggy.sourceforge.net/jnlp/mydoggyset.jnlp) shows beautiful tearaways tabs and docking support.

Answer (score 4):

For a related component, see [*How to Use Tool Bars*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html). This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848521/what-type-of-java-swing-layout-can-do-docking-and-or-anchoring/5850074#5850074) suggests that [`JToolBar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolBar.html) is quite flexible about content.

Comment: for case of that was not lost to the trash of history +1